# htaccess non existing subdomain to main domain redirection

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Need to know if this possible or not? If yes then how?

Main Domain is: `abc.com`; Subdomain is: `sub.abc.com`

I want to redirect everything like `[alphanumeric].abc.com` to `abc.com` except the sub domain (`sub.abc.com`).

e.g. `ajf43vsfvsuvfsg.abc.com` to `abc.com`; "ajfvsfvsuvfsg" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(sub\.)?abc.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://abc.com/$1 [L,R]
```

If someone types `http://blah.abc.com/some/path` in their browser's URL address bar, they'll get redirected to `http://abc.com/some/path` and the address in the address bar changes.

Comment: Thanks for response Jon,
I followed your code.
But.......,
When i tried the main domain the Browser says:
The page isn't redirecting properly       
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
The sub.abc.com is working fine 
But its not redirecting anything like blah.abc.com to abc.com

looking forward for your reply.

Comment: @Robbie.D Not sure why it's not working for you. [It works fine for me in a blank htaccess file on a new apache install](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xD78q.png). If you have other rules, they may be conflicting (redirect rules should almost always go before any type of routing).

Comment: :( Okie,im tryin' to figure the issue. BTW,Thanks for the Response Jon :)